# Search Fliter in Firebase Paginated Recyclerview Android?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, pagination, uisearchbar

**So I have been retrieving data into the recyclerview using the Firebase Paginated Ui. I want to add Search in this recyclerview , so when the user searches data he should be shown that data if present, whether it is retrieved yet or not.**

[image: So this is how the data is arranged]

**I Want to retrieve based on the studenstName child.**

**The retrieving method**

```
  // setting ListView
private void settingListView() {

    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    Query databasereference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference("Admin").child(mAuth.getUid()).child("INSTITUTE")
            .child("STUDENTS").child(programmename);

    //Initialize PagedList Configuration
    config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
            .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
            .setInitialLoadSizeHint(7)
            .setPrefetchDistance(3)
            .setPageSize(3)
            .build();

    //Initialize FirebasePagingOptions
    DatabasePagingOptions<StudentHelper> options = new DatabasePagingOptions.Builder<StudentHelper>()
            .setLifecycleOwner(this)
            .setQuery(databasereference, config, StudentHelper.class)
            .build();


    students_adapterz = new StudentsAdapter(options, Students_admin.this, progressBar,
            bottomprogressbar);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(students_adapterz);
```

}

**Search method**

```
        searcherName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
         
             // The method for retrieving based on the search.

        }
    });
```

Comment: You want to perform a search in the data being shown in the recycler view?

Comment: Or in the whole database , means in your realtime database

Comment: Entire database , because i am paginating 7 views. if i have to filter from them it doesnt make sence.